# Transform XML with XSLT in order to build table

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have XML file with content like below

```
<export>
<row>
    <field tableshort="PR" fieldno="7006">2018/12/2180000101/O</field>
    <field tableshort="PR" fieldno="7007">42</field>
    <field tableshort="AP" fieldno="4">GD S408.810</field>
    <field tableshort="AP" fieldno="40" value="0">12</field>
    <field tableshort="C001" fieldno="4">GD S408.811241</field>
    <field tableshort="C001" fieldno="4">13</field>
</row>
<row>
    <field tableshort="PR" fieldno="7006">2018/12/2180000101/O</field>
    <field tableshort="PR" fieldno="7007">42</field>
    <field tableshort="AP" fieldno="4">GD S408.810</field>
    <field tableshort="AP" fieldno="40" value="0">12</field>
    <field tableshort="C001" fieldno="4">GD S408.81XXA</field>
    <field tableshort="C001" fieldno="4">18</field>
</row>
<row>
    <field tableshort="PR" fieldno="7006">2018/12/2180000101/O</field>
    <field tableshort="PR" fieldno="7007">42</field>
    <field tableshort="AP" fieldno="4">GD S408.810</field>
    <field tableshort="AP" fieldno="40" value="0">12</field>
    <field tableshort="C001" fieldno="4">GD S408.BFSSF</field>
    <field tableshort="C001" fieldno="4">220</field>
</row>
<row>
    <field tableshort="PR" fieldno="7006">2018/12/2180000101/O</field>
    <field tableshort="PR" fieldno="7007">42</field>
    <field tableshort="AP" fieldno="4">XX1</field>
    <field tableshort="AP" fieldno="40" value="0">16</field>
    <field tableshort="C001" fieldno="4">GD S408.811241</field>
    <field tableshort="C001" fieldno="4">21</field>
</row>
<row>
    <field tableshort="PR" fieldno="7006">2018/12/2180000101/O</field>
    <field tableshort="PR" fieldno="7007">42</field>
    <field tableshort="AP" fieldno="4">XX1</field>
    <field tableshort="AP" fieldno="40" value="0">16</field>
    <field tableshort="C001" fieldno="4">GD S408.81FSS</field>
    <field tableshort="C001" fieldno="4">13</field>
</row>
<row>
    <field tableshort="PR" fieldno="7006">2018/12/2180000101/O</field>
    <field tableshort="PR" fieldno="7007">42</field>
    <field tableshort="AP" fieldno="4">XX1</field>
    <field tableshort="AP" fieldno="40" value="0">16</field>
    <field tableshort="C001" fieldno="4">GD S408.811PKA</field>
    <field tableshort="C001" fieldno="4">17</field>
</row>
```

and I would like to use XSLT (1.0) transformation in order to transform this content and achieve effect like on attached picture and this is html table with marked mapping

[Screen with value mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9Dww.png)

Attached XML is only example. We have XML with more than 1000 rows so I need to build a loop or few loops that will fetch those values automatically.

Here is the code with I'm currently working :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" media-type="text/xml" />

<xsl:param name="ImageFolder">.</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="Font">Verdana</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="FontHeader">Cera Pro</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="FontSize">8</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="CellPadding">2.0</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="CellSpacing">0.0</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="HeaderBackgroundColor">#92bcde</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="HeaderBorderColor">#92bcde</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="HeaderBorderWidth">1.0</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="AlternateCellBackgroundColor">#F0F0F0</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="Leading">8</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="Count"/>
<xsl:param name="Ext">.png</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="PozCheck"/>
<xsl:param name="PozCheck5"/>
<xsl:param name="count" />


<xsl:template match="/" >


<xsl:variable name="NumberOfColumns" 
select="count(export/fields/field)"/>
<itext pagesize="A4" orientation="portrait">

<xsl:for-each select="//row">


<xsl:variable name="Duplicate1">
<xsl:value-of select="field[@fieldno='141' and @tableshort='AP']" />
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="Duplicate2">
<xsl:value-of select="field[@fieldno='7007' and @tableshort='C001']" />
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="Loop1">
<xsl:value-of select="field[@fieldno='40' and @tableshort='AP']" />
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="LoopBreak2">
<xsl:value-of select="field[@fieldno='40' and @tableshort='AP']" />
</xsl:variable>


<xsl:variable name="LoopBreak1">
<xsl:value-of select="field[@fieldno='40' and @tableshort='AP']" />
</xsl:variable>


<xsl:value-of select="'_'"/>
<xsl:value-of select="field[@fieldno='40' and @tableshort='AP']" />


<xsl:for-each select="//row">

<xsl:variable name="Loop2">
<xsl:value-of select="field[@fieldno='40' and @tableshort='AP']" />
</xsl:variable>


<xsl:if test="$Loop1=$Loop2">
<xsl:value-of select="'_'"/>
<xsl:value-of select="field[@fieldno='4' and @tableshort='C001']" />


</xsl:if>


</xsl:for-each>


</xsl:for-each> 
</itext>

</xsl:template>
```

Could you please advise how to achieve this?

Comment: Please post your best attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch. Also show the expected output **as code** (XSLT does not produce pictures).

Comment: Can I ask for response ?

Comment: Hi  @michael.hor257k,Sorry for that.  I am fresh in XSLT  and on this forum. I have add some additional information. Please check.

Comment: Hi, Could you please advise, whether there is a possibility to achieve the desired effect ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: At this point I have no idea what your question is. Apparently no one else does either, since there are no answers. I suggest you spend your time making your question clear (consult the help section) instead of adding these comments that serve no purpose.

Comment: Hello,I have modified my description so maybe now you will be able to see what should be done.

Comment: Hello, is everything clear in this this subject ? Is it clear what I want to achieve ?